# Can I use JS variables to access Laravel data? How should I write it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

```
let name = $(this).attr("name");
let value = "{{ $response['" + name + "'] }}";
```

I am running this in $(document).ready()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code shouldn't work, because the php code will only be compiled first and then returned to the client(haha,That's correct, right?);
Let js receive php variable value in blade

```js
let value = `{{$a}}`;//`{{$a['hello']}}`
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.
I understand. Is it possible to expand all the data received and search for data in JS? I will try that.

Comment: Yes, I am. I have successfully solved the problem. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Larvel has a helper to include json to be used in js https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/blade#rendering-json

Comment: The part you gave me helped me when I was having trouble getting an array of json data. I appreciate it very much.